# Using jqPlot in Onsen UI in Phonegap project

Tags: cordova, jqplot, onsen-ui

I'm trying to draw a chart in Onsen UI using jqPlot on a Phonegap project, but I can't.
I use pure javascript, no AngularJS.
jqPlot is HTML5 compatible, so I think is Phonegap / Onsen UI compatible.

See page1.html, there is the javascript lines to show the chart.

Maybe is a template problem, or Onsen UI can't contain this type of code, but I think that is possible.
Any ideas?
Thanks!!

I try this:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">

<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
 <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
 <title>My App</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/onsen/css/onsenui.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/onsen-css-components-blue-basic-theme.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/app.css" />

 <script src="lib/onsen/js/angular/angular.js"></script>
 <script src="lib/onsen/js/onsenui.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jqplot/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.highlighter.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.cursor.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jqplot/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jqplot/plugins/jqplot.canvasAxisLabelRenderer.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/jqplot/jquery.jqplot.min.css" />

 <script>
  ons.bootstrap();

  ons.ready(function () {
  });
 </script>
</head>
<body>

 <ons-sliding-menu menu-page="menu.html" main-page="page1.html" side="left" var="menu" type="reveal" max-slide-distance="260px" swipable="true">
 </ons-sliding-menu>

 <ons-template id="menu.html">
  <ons-page modifier="menu-page">
   <ons-toolbar modifier="transparent"></ons-toolbar>

   <ons-list class="menu-list">
    <ons-list-item class="menu-item" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('page1.html', {closeMenu: true})">
     <ons-icon icon="fa-plus"></ons-icon>
     Facturación Anual
    </ons-list-item>

    <ons-list-item class="menu-item" ng-click="menu.setMainPage('page2.html', {closeMenu: true})">
     <ons-icon icon="fa-bookmark"></ons-icon>
     Ranking Productos
    </ons-list-item>
   </ons-list>
  </ons-page>
 </ons-template>


 <ons-template id="page1.html">
  <ons-page id="canvasPage">
   <ons-toolbar>
    <div class="left">
     <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggle()">
      <ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" size="28px" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon>
     </ons-toolbar-button>
    </div>
    <div class="center">Page 111</div>
   </ons-toolbar>

    <div style="width:30%">
     <div>
      <script>
       ons.ready(function () {
        var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [[3, 7, 9, 1, 5, 3, 8, 2, 5]]);
       });
      </script>
     </div>
    </div>
  </ons-page>
 </ons-template>

 <ons-template id="page2.html">
  <ons-page>
   <ons-toolbar>
    <div class="left">
     <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="menu.toggle()">
      <ons-icon icon="ion-navicon" size="28px" fixed-width="false"></ons-icon>
     </ons-toolbar-button>
    </div>
    <div class="center">Page 222</div>
   </ons-toolbar>
  </ons-page>
 </ons-template>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the JavaScript is even executed. It's easy to check with `console.log(msg)`.

You've put some JavaScript code inside an `<ons-template>` tag. When you navigate to the page it will be inserted into the DOM but the JavaScript won't be executed.

You shouldn't put JavaScript inline in your HTML, please look up how to properly structure your JavaScript.

Comment: Hi!, thnaks for your answer!
I'm using ons-sliding-menu, where you think I need to put my javascript code?.
Thanks!!!